# GLSL shader that scroll texture

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

How to scrolling a texture on a plane? 
So I have a plane with a texture, can I use a shader to scroll left from right (infinite) the texture on it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Setup the texture wrapping mode using

   `glTexParameteri(TextureID, L_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)`
2. Add the float uniform named `Time` to your texturing shader
3. Use something like `texture2D(sampler, u + Time, v)` while fetching texture sample.
4. Update the `Time` uniform using some timer in your code.

Here's a GLSL shader:

```
/*VERTEX_PROGRAM*/

in vec4 in_Vertex;
in vec4 in_TexCoord;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
     gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * in_Vertex;

     TexCoord = vec2( in_TexCoord );
}

/*FRAGMENT_PROGRAM*/

in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D Texture0;

/// Updated in external code
uniform float Time;

out vec4 out_FragColor;

void main()
{
   /// "u" coordinate is altered
   out_FragColor = texture( Texture0, vec2(TexCoord.x + Time, TexCoord.y) );
}
```