# Android OpenGLES Scrolling Background

Tags: android, opengl-es, game-engine

I have a scrolling background by making it dynamic and giving it a velocity to have it scrolling. I could have another image and loop them, but this seems a little messy and I am quite inexperienced with OpenGLES 1.1 and thought there may be a better way to do this.

What is the easiest/best way to have a scrolling background in OPenGLES 1 on android?

Comment: Do you want to repeat once it goes out of bounds?

Comment: yes, That right. once and side leaves the screen on the x axis, the image will roll around again from the other side. Looping the same image. Or even looping more than one image if possible.

Comment: You can animated uv coordinates and setup the texture as REPEAT. That will sure do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a code example for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual implementation may depend on which OpenGL version you are targeting. For any version you will need to specify texture parameters as follow:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

And in order to animate the texture coordinates you can either change your texture coordinates client side (send down updated texture coordinates) or use a texture matrix. For OpenGL ES 1.x  you would change the matrix mode with `glMatrixMode` to `GL_TEXTURE` and translate it using `glTranslate`.

Sorry I don't have example for this, those are some guidelines.

**EDIT:** For an GLSL shader look here: [GLSL shader that scroll texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847985/glsl-shader-that-scroll-texture)

Comment: Thanks for that Trax. Its just what I was after. I will give it a shot.